# Uploading issues with an asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5

I have created my first website using asp.net 3.5 .
I have used App_Code for managing my source code files.

Now, after completion:

1. List item
2. What needs to be uploaded to the server ?
3. Do uploading all file including webforms files, source code files make any sense ?
4. Please provide your own suggestions apart from these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look in to one of these several very good tutorials and articles about deploying ASP.NET applications.

- [How to Deploy ASP.NET](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Deploy-ASP.NET.aspx)
- [15 Seconds: Deploying ASP.NET](http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/030806.htm)
- [Deploying ASP.NET Applications on IIS 6](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/2f45f2ea-bcf8-4d23-9f15-5caf7ebdc2ef.mspx?mfr=true)
- [Deploying ASP.NET Applications](http://www.startvbdotnet.com/aspsite/extras/deploy.aspx)

Now to your thoughts on what should be uploaded and what not. If you understand the asp.net cycle and how the files are processed by the webserver, it would be easy to know that all files need to be uploaded. But since this is your first application you probably don't have that knowledge.

So, to save you some reading time, **Upload everything**. In older versions such as 1.1 you had to compile all your source-code into binaries, which you don't have to anymore, but you can, it's up to you.

I However prefere to upload all the files without compiling it to binaries, makes it easier to manage once they are on the server.

The webserver will upon request ( first request ) compile these and then use the compiled files on other requests, this is the short answer anyway, this is why the load-time is longer the first time and the other times it's ( suppose to ) go faster.

Also, worht to know is that if you change the web.config, the application will re-compile.

**So just drag n' drop em' to your webb-location and start playing!**

Comment: I don't think its a good idea to put source files on a web server like that - not when you don't have to.

Comment: It's a good idea for a beginner to understand more than one way. My answer clearly states that you CAN do it and that it was Mandatory in older versions of .net. But I disslike it when it's just me playing around with the files anyway.

Comment: I understand the concept of uploading all files. But what if, I dont want to upload source files.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the App_Code folder, it sounds like you are using a web site project type.  In this case, the easiest thing to do is just xCopy all of the files up to the webserver.  IIS will then do Just In Time compilation (JIT) the first time a page is hit, and will compile your code on the fly.

rgds,

Paul

Answer (score -1):

1. All content files (i.e. aspx, ascx, asmx, asax, js, css, htm, jpg, gif, png) and DLLs need to be deployed to the server. I recommend using the Visual Studio "Publish..." option on the Build menu to do this for you. It can deploy to a folder (which you can then copy to somewhere else if you like), an FTP site or to an IIS virtual directory.
2. Uploading your .cs or .vb files is not necessary. It will still work if you do but it's probably safer not to. There's a remote possibility that IIS will have a vulnerability or a sysadmin will make a mistake and your source code will end up being served to the public.
3. In Visual Studio you could could do File -> New Web Setup Project and build an MSI to do it. [This article](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Deploy-ASP.NET.aspx) and [This article](http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/030806.htm) have more details on this option.

Comment: Why would uploading .cs and .vb-files be a security issue?

Comment: I think because you are releasing your source code to an untrusted network.  If your web server is compromised, so is your source code...

Comment: Also, if IIS was configured carelessly it may serve up your source files. That would then show where you're not properly escaping user generated input and leave you open to SQL Injection or XSS attacks. In theory no sysadmin would be stupid enough to let this happen, but it does happen. So I wouldn't recommend to people that they upload their source files.

Comment: And if your were to invite people over for dinner and the computer is on, they can upload the files to the internet! Seriously, we don't live in russia. And people should just learn to configure it correctly or just leave it to those who can. And if you are as dumb as letting IIS serve your source-files, maybe you should look into another profession. Also if you are so paranoid maybe your shouldn't code .NET, noone is safe.

Comment: OMG you leave you computer ON when people come over for dinner! ;)